# CRUD and FLS enforcement

Tags: apex, security-review, crud, fls

I have an Account list and I want to update it.

I want to testing object and field level security enforcement but I'm wondering what I have to test :

1 - if Account object is updatable ? (if it's possible)

2 - if the fields in my select query is updatable ?

3 - only if the Account Name is updatable ?

Here the code for these three propositions :

```
List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id, Name, BillingStreet FROM Account];
...
// 1 : I don't know if it's possible to test if an object is updatable ?

// 2 : test all the fields in the select query
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isUpdateable() && !Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.BillingStreet.isUpdateable() ){
    update acc;
}

// 3 : test only the Name
if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isUpdateable()){
    update acc;
}
```

Comment: You want to use the schema field describe methods on the Account object. But first you need to get the tokens. I have code someplace I could share, but its late and I don't have time to look for it. You should be able search on Schema Describe to find what you need in an existing post. If not try using this search engine: http://findsf.info/.

Answer (score 3):

So

1. Yes its of course possible you can do it in two ways (which essentialy are the same)

   ```
   Schema.sObjectType.Account.isUpdateable()
   ```

   and

   ```
   Account.sObjectType.getDescribe().isUpdateable()
   ```
2. ```
   if (!Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.Name.isUpdateable() &&
       !Schema.sObjectType.Account.fields.BillingStreet.isUpdateable() ){
           update acc; }
   ```

   That will check actually even 3 things

   - Edit access to Name field
   - Edit access to BillingStreet field
   - Edit access to Account itself
3. This will check Name and Account access

Also remember about `with sharing` and `without sharing` for class

With sharing checks if the user have access (read, read/write, none) to a RECORD and not object itself. So even if user have access to edit fields/object but doesnt have access to record, that user wont be able to edit record.

There are of course cases when user have view all/modify all on object or view all data/modify all data (system admins).

Without sharing ommits that restrictions but it needs to be used only when you have that kinda specific requirement

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all three propositions are possible to update on your Account Object.
Below link will help you more.
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS

Comment: Can you please add a space before the ']', it's messing with the URL

Comment: love that every year salesforce breaks all their documentation links :)